# Add a space between number and word R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I want to add a space between numbers and words R.

For example, I'd like for `"1in10"`  to be `"1 in 10"`. And, for `"9months"` to be `"9 months"`.

Thank you so much for the help.

`mystring1 <- "1in10"`

`mystring2 <- "9months"`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option with regex lookaround to match the junction between a digit/non-digit or a non-digit/digit and replace with space

```
gsub("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", " ", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "1 in 10"  "9 months"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c( "1in10", "9months")
```